# How can I use Github Actions to trigger downloading a static copy of a website and push to S3?

Tags: wget, github-actions

I am trying to use `Github` actions on the Push event to my master branch for running a `wget` command to mirror a website and download its contents as static files and then zip them together for uploading to an s3 bucket. Here is my `test_events.yml` file stored under `.github/workflows` in my git repo:

```
name: create a mirror of website and zip the saved contents

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  mirror-website:
    name: mirrors the website
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: wget
      uses: wei/wget@v1
      with:
        args: -O logfile.txt -P ./actions/ https://adappt.co.uk

  zip-files:
    name: Zips the Saved file
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Prepares a zip file
      uses: montudor/action-zip@v1.0.0
      with:
        args: zip -qq -r adappt_co_uk.zip . -i /actions/adappt.co.uk
```

Problem is whenever I push a change in my repo, the action gets triggered and gets completed without errors. But it does not save the web files to the given location, and hence, doesn't perform the zip operation as well.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way apart from using wget?

Comment: You say `./actions` in one place but `/actions` in another.

Comment: I you are not wedded to wget, then you are asking the wrong question: https://xyproblem.info.  I'll update your question for you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Inigo. This question perfectly sums up my task. :)

Comment: Why are you using all sorts of actions for simple tasks? Just use `run: wget...` or `run: 7z...` to do whatever you want, in one job with multiple steps. This way you can first test the same commands locally, and just paste them to the action when you find a working combination.